# First image selected in coolbar (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

After the start of my application the coolbar is loaded and the first item is selected automatically. I don't want that. Is it possible to remove this selection?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grMQX.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because that button (or rather the toolbar) currently has the focus. To remove the focus you have to set it to another control. Did you implement the `setFocus()` method of your "Übersicht" view?